# how to organize code while using multiple jpanel tabs in swing

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

I am new to swing programming. I have created a Jtabbedpane and added 4 jpanel to it.

all the button and labels in the 4 jpanel are in the same java class and is starting to look cluttered. I am using Intellij. It would be nice if I can put all the items and events related to one panel in its own class so 4 classes for 4  panels and just a reference to those classes in the main frame. Not sure how to do this as most of the code is generated by the IDE.

If there is a way to do this or a tutorial that does this please let me know.

Comment: I wouldn't advise using Intellij's automated Swing GUI generator if you're building a complex GUI. The code is unreadable and unmaintainable also it doesn't allow you to change many properties of the components that are normally editable in Swing. My suggestion would be that you code your own GUI without automated code generator of Intellij.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can break this up rather easily. Anywhere the code generates a new panel, probably as a "build" method, you can pull that out and make in a structure in another class. An example would look something like this:

```
// New class file named testPanel.java
public class testPanel extends JPanel{
    // Constructor
    public textPanel(){
        // Add an example button
        JButton btn_exit = new JButton("Exit");
        btn_exit.addActionListener(new ExitButtonListener());
        buttons.add(btn_exit);
    }

    // Private inner class which does event handling for our example button
    private class ExitButtonListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

   // Add whatever other code you like here or above or anywhere else :)
}
```

Then to use that panel in your main JFrame, you can aggregate it like this:

```
private testPanel pnl_test  = new textPanel();
// You can place this in the constructor 
// for your JFrame without the "MyJFrame."
// But for demonstration purposes I will include it
MyJFrame.add(pnl_test);
// Or if you were placing a panel inside of another panel,
// you can use the same method associated with a JPanel object
MyJPanel.add(pnl_test);
```